# Programmatically determining who GPG signed a file

Tags: encryption, gnupg

I want to programmatically determine who has signed a GPG clear sign file. Running `gpg --verify` will tell me this, but it does so in a human-readable format. Is it possible to get this result in a machine-readable format?

I am not looking for methods to parse the human readable format, as it may change in future GPG versions. I need a robust solution.

Comment: What exactly do you feel is the difference between human readable and machine readable? Honestly in either case a parser has to be written.  Seems sort of trivial to parse the data returned by that command.

Comment: @Ramhound: The difference is that human-readable outputs vary depending on program version, system language, date format, locale (character set)... The parser would therefore need to be several times more complex.

Comment: @grawity - Alright.  My statement was to see if I could get provided clarification so the question is clear.  I could generate a parser without a problem, everything you list, would remain the same for anything I wrote.

Comment: For example, the [keybase-client](http://git.io/fASyCw) code at first [tried to parse](http://git.io/6J7BWA) the human-readable format, but ended up having to account for timezones (the output contains local time); different amounts of information between versions ("skip arbitrarily many lines"); user's settings (long vs short vs 0xlong vs 0xshort key IDs)... The new code is about the same size, but is easier to understand, obtains more information, and it's more-or-less promised that the output format will remain the same.

Comment: In other words, it's a choice between writing robust code, and "not a bug, it works on MY machine".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For this, GnuPG has the machine-readable `--status-fd` format:

```
^ gpg --status-fd=1 --verify test.asc
gpg: Signature made Sat 01 Feb 2014 19:37:53 EET using RSA key ID C1B52632
[GNUPG:] SIG_ID LI0kgmtHFCacIrSKM9uxpc3B2jI 2014-02-01 1391276273
[GNUPG:] GOODSIG D24F6CB2C1B52632 Mantas Mikulėnas <grawity@nullroute.eu.org>
gpg: Good signature from "Mantas Mikulėnas <grawity@nullroute.eu.org>"
gpg:                 aka "Mantas Mikulėnas <grawity@gmail.com>"
[GNUPG:] NOTATION_NAME issuer-fpr@notations.openpgp.fifthhorseman.net
[GNUPG:] NOTATION_DATA 2357E10CEF4F7ED27E233AD5D24F6CB2C1B52632
[GNUPG:] VALIDSIG 2357E10CEF4F7ED27E233AD5D24F6CB2C1B52632 2014-02-01 1391276273                        0 4 0 1 2 00 2357E10CEF4F7ED27E233AD5D24F6CB2C1B52632
[GNUPG:] TRUST_ULTIMATE
```

The output format is documented in [doc/DETAILS](http://git.gnupg.org/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=gnupg.git;a=blob_plain;f=doc/DETAILS). (The messages are intermixed with human-readable ones because I pointed `gpg` to fd #1, aka stdout. A program could easily use two separate fd's for this purpose, e.g. using `pipe()`.)

Comment: Thanks! I was playing around with `--with-colons` the whole time, which didn't work.

Comment: Note to self, and others that are interested: `--with-colons` is useful for parsing key output, such as `--list-keys`.